# Access Key Vault value with dash in name in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have a devops yaml pipeline that utilizes terraform to create my Azure resources. It creates a database, a key vault and then adds a secret to the key vault for the sql database connection string. As per the Key Vault conventions for creating objects/properties, the Key Vault secret name is `Sql--ConnectionString`. I need to access this secret value to run a migration as a part of the devops pipeline and can't figure out how to do so.

The relevant part of the devops.yaml looks as follows:

```
steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: <SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>
      KeyVaultName: <KEY_VAULT_NAME>

  - pwsh: |
      cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/migrations
      Write-Host ${Sql--ConnectionString}
      Write-Host $(TILAzFunctionCustomDomainVerificationId)
```

On the Azure Key Vault step, I see the following:
[image]
which shows me that my keys are being pulled in, including the Sql one.

Then the powershell step outputs the following:
[image]
As can be seen, the value with the `--` in the name isn't shown, but the one without is. I've tried a bunch of different approaches, all without any luck. I would assume the key name is getting transformed somehow, but I can't find information on how that is taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line, you are using the wrong type of bracket:

```
Write-Host ${Sql--ConnectionString}
```

it should be

```
Write-Host $(Sql--ConnectionString)
```

Note that the rules for powershell variables do not apply here; this isn't a powershell variable, it's an [azure devops pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables) so it needs the round brackets, just like on the previous row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately it is incorrect. As per the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#variable-names-that-include-special-characters), this is the correct syntax for a variable with a `-` in the name.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right there. Your doc is describing *powershell variables*, but your pipeline is trying to evaluate a [pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables).

Comment: It appears as though you are correct and I am wrong. Thank you!